# Windows 7 Map CTRL + j to the Down Arrow Key

Tags: windows, keyboard, keymapping

I have been searching for months for a way to map a key combination (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>something</kbd>) to a directional key (like down or up).

I desperately want in Visual Studio to be able to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> and have the cursor move down a line. I hate having to move my hands off of the home row to move up and down for things like intellisense or even just navigating up and down lines.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I would be ok with a Visual Studio-only solution, but something that works at the OS level would be ideal since this kind of navigation would be nice in any editor window and for instance SQL Server Management Studio also has intellisense.

I haven't considered any macro hotkey type solutions since they could conflict with in-app hotkeys (for instance if <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> were assigned to something in Visual Studio already)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is nothing out there exists that would do this. I have done a lot of research.

I am now using Autohotkey instead of what would have been ideal. I have been familiar with this application for years and it does a pretty good job, but doesn't work across remote desktop for instance and so doesn't quite fill the need.

I mapped <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to do up, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> to be down, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> as left and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> for right.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how did you mapped the key using AutoHotKey. I am also looking for a similar AutoHotKey script.

Comment: @manavm-n see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425458/how-to-map-arrow-keys-with-an-autohotkey-script-like-vim/31425459#31425459

Answer (score 1):

VS-only solution is simple.

At least in Visual Studio 2017 you can assign Ctrl+XXX key combinations to corresponding commands for Text Editor.

```
CharLeft
CharLeftExtend
CharRight
CharRightExtend
LineUp
LineUpExtend
LineDown
LineDownExtend
PageUp
PageUpExtend
PageDown
PageDownExtend
LineStart
LineStartExtend
Delete
DeleteBackwards
WordPrevious
WordPreviousExtend
WordNext
WordNextExtend
```

and so on.

All using standard Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard settings dialog.