# How to map arrow keys with an AutoHotKey script like Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Referring to question [Windows 7 Map CTRL + j to the Down Arrow Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302221/windows-7-map-ctrl-j-to-the-down-arrow-key)

How can I map the arrow keys with AutoHotKey like vim?

```
Ctrl+h = Move left 
Ctrl+j = Move down 
Ctrl+k = Move up 
Ctrl+l = Move right
```

Comment: Literally no reason for this to have been down voted except by an Emacs user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an AutoHotKey-script like this:

```
^h::
   Send, {Left down}{Left up}
Return

^j::
   Send, {Down down}{Down up}
Return

^k::
   Send, {Up down}{Up up}
Return

^l::
   Send, {Right down}{Right up}
Return
```

Comment: Thank you so much, using vim keybindings with a new happy hacking keyboard is awesome!